# Kodein-DI Gradle dependency in common module

Tags: kotlin, kodein

I'd like to define a Kodein-DI module in common Kotlin code (so I could import it from both JS and JVM modules).

What Gradle dependency should I add to `commonMain`?

Comment: I'm not completely clear on the context here. Can you point at code or perhaps create a simple sample project with the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

My issue seems to be solved, see https://github.com/Kodein-Framework/Kodein-DI/issues/177#issuecomment-457915559 for details.